# Is there a name for mapping recursive data types based on terminals and their ancestries?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, functor

Let's say I have a type that looks like this:

```
data Term a = Terminal a
| Application (Term a) (Term a)
| Abstraction String (Term a)
```

Now, I want to map `Term a` to `Term b`. Ideally, I would be able to do this using a function  `(a -> b)` and just implement `fmap`. However, that doesn't work for me. The map from `Terminal a` to `Terminal b` is dependent not just on the value of `a`, but also the values of the ancestors of `Terminal a` (e.g. the depth of `Terminal a`). So it's more like `[Term a] -> b` which is messy, so I'm trying to decompose this into something cleaner.

So really, what I need is something like 2 functions and an initial value: `(c -> Term a -> c)` can be called on each of the ancestors in order to accumulate whatever we want. (I guess it's equivalent to `([Term a] -> c)` but I'm not sure whether that confuses the situation or helps.) `(c -> a -> b)` can map `Terminal a` to `Terminal b`. (We also need an initial value of type `c`)

So I'm definition a function with the following type signature:

```
notQuiteANatTrans :: (c -> Term a -> c) -> (c -> a -> b) -> c -> Term a -> Term b
```

This isn't a natural transformation. (I don't think) Or if it is, it's mapping something like `[Term a] -> [Term b]` where each of those is the path from the root of the tree to the `Terminal`. Is there a name for this? Is there maybe a different way to decompose my arrows in order to get something cleaner?

Comment: I don't know if it helps but this can be seen as a specialization of [`transverse` from recursion-schemes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.2.2.2/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:transverse) with `f` equal to `(->) c`.

Comment: Not quite sure how you're using (calling) the first function, is that meant to produce a `c` value for the children? What is the `c` value that you pass into the second function? Might  help if you could show an implementation for `notQuiteANatTrans` doing the desired things

Comment: You might like [dual-tree](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dual-tree).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand the problem, so apologies if the following goes off on an irrelevant tangent...

> The map from `Terminal a` to `Terminal b` is dependent not just on the value of `a`, but also the values of the ancestors of `Terminal a` (e.g. the depth of `Terminal a`).

This sounds reminiscent of having to examine a tree to find, for example, its depth. For a tree, you can do this with its *catamorphism* - see e.g. [the examples for foldTree](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Tree.html#v:foldTree).

In general, if you know the catamorphism for a datatype, you can derive most other (perhaps all?) useful functions from it. So what's the catamorphism for `Term a`?

## F-Algebra

You can derive the catamorphism from [F-Algebras](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2017/02/28/f-algebras/). I'll follow the process I've used in [my own article series on catamorphisms](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/04/29/catamorphisms).

Define the underlying endofunctor like this:

```
data TermF a c =
    TerminalF a
  | ApplicationF c c
  | AbstractionF String c
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor (TermF a) where
  fmap _ (TerminalF a) = TerminalF a
  fmap f (ApplicationF x y) = ApplicationF (f x) (f y)
  fmap f (AbstractionF s x) = AbstractionF s (f x)
```

This enables you to figure out the catamorphism by using [typed holes](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Typed_holes):

```
termF = cata alg
  where alg      (TerminalF x) = _
        alg (ApplicationF x y) = _
        alg (AbstractionF s c) = _
```

If you try to compile this sketch, the compiler will complain about the type holes and tell you what you need. I used this process to arrive at this function:

```
termF :: (a -> c) -> (c -> c -> c) -> (String -> c -> c) -> Fix (TermF a) -> c
termF t appl abst = cata alg
  where alg      (TerminalF x) = t x
        alg (ApplicationF x y) = appl x y
        alg (AbstractionF s x) = abst s x
```

The catamorphism requires a mapper of the underlying type `a -> c`, as well as 'accumulators' for each of the recursive nodes.

## Isomorphism

`Fix (TermF a)` is isomorphic with `Term a`, as witnessed by these two conversion functions:

```
toTerm :: Fix (TermF a) -> Term a
toTerm = termF Terminal Application Abstraction

fromTerm :: Term a -> Fix (TermF a)
fromTerm = ana coalg
  where coalg      (Terminal x) = TerminalF x
        coalg (Application x y) = ApplicationF x y
        coalg (Abstraction s x) = AbstractionF s x
```

This means that you can easily define the catamorphism for `Term a` using the catamorphism for `Fix (TermF a)`. Let's call it `foldTerm`, as that's probably a little more idiomatic:

```
foldTerm :: (a -> c) -> (c -> c -> c) -> (String -> c -> c) -> Term a -> c
foldTerm t appl abst = termF t appl abst . fromTerm
```

Now that you know the type of `foldTerm`, you can throw away all the `TermF` machinery and implement it directly.

## Direct implementation

Again, you can use typed holes for a simpler, more direct implementation:

```
foldTerm :: (a -> c) -> (c -> c -> c) -> (String -> c -> c) -> Term a -> c
foldTerm t appl abst      (Terminal x) = _
foldTerm t appl abst (Application x y) = _
foldTerm t appl abst (Abstraction s x) = _
```

The compiler will tell you what you need, and it's fairly clear that the implementation must be something like this:

```
foldTerm :: (a -> c) -> (c -> c -> c) -> (String -> c -> c) -> Term a -> c
foldTerm t appl abst      (Terminal x) = t x
foldTerm t appl abst (Application x y) = appl (recurse x) (recurse y)
  where recurse = foldTerm t appl abst
foldTerm t appl abst (Abstraction s x) = abst s (foldTerm t appl abst x)
```

Keep in mind that the output of `foldTerm` can be any type `c`, including `Term b`: `c ~ Term b`. Does that enable you do do what you're asking about?

Comment: A catamorphism is very useful for bottom-up folds, but it sounds like OP is trying to implement a top-down one. Let's say you have a `Term String`, and you want to convert that into a `Term [String]` where each `Terminal` has a path of the `Abstraction` strings that led to it. How to do that using `foldTerm`?

Comment: @Bergi If I understand you correctly, something like this: `ex t = foldTerm (\s acc -> Terminal (s : acc)) (\f g acc -> Application (f acc) (g acc)) (\s f acc -> Abstraction s (f (s : acc))) t []`. This example lists the 'path' in reverse order - i.e. it starts with the node, then the immediate parent, then that node's parent, etc. I admit, however, that I haven't tested it extensively, since I'm still only guessing at what the requirements might be.

Comment: Ah, right, I forgot about the power of the intermediate function approach!