# removing explicit recursion by replacing catamorphism

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, recursion-schemes, comonad

I have this AST data structure

```
data AST = Integer Int
         | Let String AST AST
         | Plus AST AST
         | Minus AST AST
         | Times AST AST
         | Variable String
         | Boolean Bool
         | If AST AST AST
         | Lambda String AST Type Type
         | Application AST AST
         | And AST AST
         | Or AST AST
         | Quot AST AST
         | Rem AST AST
         | Negate AST
         | Eq AST AST
         | Leq AST AST
         | Geq AST AST
         | Neq AST AST
         | Lt AST AST
         | Gt AST AST
```

and this evaluation code:

```
eval :: AST -> AST
eval = cata go where
    go :: ASTF (AST) -> AST
    go (LetF var e e') = eval $ substVar (var, e) e'
    go (PlusF (Integer n) (Integer m)) = Integer (n + m)
    go (MinusF (Integer n) (Integer m)) = Integer (n - m)
    go (TimesF (Integer n) (Integer m)) = Integer (n * m)
    go (QuotF (Integer n) (Integer m)) = Integer (quot n m)
    go (RemF (Integer n) (Integer m)) = Integer (rem n m)
    go (IfF (Boolean b) e e') = if b then e else e'
    go (ApplicationF (Lambda var e _ _) e') = eval $ substVar (var, e') e
    go (AndF (Boolean b) (Boolean b')) = Boolean (b && b')
    go (OrF (Boolean b) (Boolean b')) = Boolean (b || b')
    go (NegateF (Boolean b)) = Boolean (not b)
    go (EqF e e') = Boolean (e == e')
    go (NeqF e e') = Boolean (e /= e')
    go (LeqF (Integer n) (Integer m)) = Boolean (n <= m)
    go (GeqF (Integer n) (Integer m)) = Boolean (n >= m)
    go (LtF (Integer n) (Integer m)) = Boolean (n < m)
    go (GtF (Integer n) (Integer m)) = Boolean (n > m)
    go astf = embed astf
```

I feel like there should be away to remove the explicit recursion for 'let' and application, but I'm not sure exactly which recursion scheme I should reach for. Which recursion scheme(s) can be used to remove recursion in this case and similar cases and do you have any good ways of identifying situations where said recursion scheme is applicable?

Comment: You can always (I think) derive the catamorphism from an [F-algebra](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2017/02/28/f-algebras/). I wrote [an article series](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2019/04/29/catamorphisms) with several examples, if that helps...

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/72247301/126014 for yet another example.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Sorry, I don't think I made my question clear enough. My issue isn't producing an falgebra/catamorphism, my issue is that when using catamorphisms explicit recursion is still used. My question is there a DIFFERENT recursion scheme that lets me side step this issue?

Answer (score 5):

`eval` isn't directly expressible as a catamorphism because `eval (Let x e e')` applies `eval` to `subst (x, eval e) e'`, which is not a subterm of `Let x e e'` (`e` or `e'`). Instead, consider the composition of `eval` and substitution. If you generalize substitution `subst` to substitute many variables at once with `substs`, then you can get the following equation:

```
(eval . substs s) (Let x e e')
= eval (Let x (substs s e) (substs s e'))
= (eval . subst (x, (eval . substs s) e) . substs s) e'

-- by (subst xe . substs s) = substs (xe : s)

= (eval . substs ((x, (eval . substs s) e) : s)) e'
```

where we do have a function of the form `(eval . substs _)` applied to both subterms `e` and `e'`. In order to account for the parameter of `substs`, you can use `cata` with an F-algebra where the carrier is a function `ASTF (Sub -> AST) -> Sub -> AST`, then you get to pass a different substitution `Sub` to each subterm.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Functor.Foldable (cata)
import Data.Functor.Foldable.TH (makeBaseFunctor)
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)

type Id = String
data AST
  = Let Id AST AST
  | Var Id
  | Int Int
  | Plus AST AST

type Sub = [(Id, AST)]

makeBaseFunctor ''AST

evalSubsts :: AST -> Sub -> AST
evalSubsts = cata go where
  go (LetF x e e') s = e' ((x, e s) : s)
  go (VarF x) s = fromJust (lookup x s)
  go (IntF n) _ = Int n
  go (PlusF e e') s =
    let (Int n, Int m) = (e s, e' s) in
    Int (n + m)
  -- Or this:
  -- go (PlusF e e') = liftA2 plus e e'
  --   where plus (Int n) (Int m) = Int (n + m)

eval :: AST -> AST
eval e = evalSubsts e []
```

Another way to think of `evalSubsts` is as an evaluator using an environment, mapping variables to values. Then to bind a variable, rather than to do a substitution, is just to insert its value in the environment, which gets looked up once you reach a `Var` node.

Comment: I thought this worked, but the I tried running it on `(Let "x" (Integer 1) (Let "y" (Integer 2) (Application (Lambda "x" (Plus (Variable "x") (Variable "y")) IntType IntType) (Integer 3)))` and it returned 3 instead of 5. `let x = 1 in let y = 2 in \x -> x + y :: Int -> Int 3` is the unparsed code.

Comment: @Aceshinigami If you have a followup problem, feel free to open a new question with the details. I encourage you to minimize your AST (and your example) as far as possible before you do so. In any case, we will need to see the code you wrote to even have a chance at helping, and that's unlikely to be comfortably transmitted via a comment.

Comment: @li-yao-xia will it be related to?
https://youtu.be/jWS7AMBXGkU?list=PLF1Z-APd9zK5uFc8FKr_di9bfsYv8-lbc&t=1400

Answer (score 2):

Continuing on the `evalSubsts` approach from @li-yao-xia, let's try to add lambdas and applications to our language.  We start by extending `AST`:

```hs
data AST
  ...
  | Lam Id AST
  | App AST AST
```

But, how do we write our `LamF` case in `evalSubst`?

```hs
  go (LamF x e) s = ???
```

We want our lambdas to be statically (lexically) scoped, so we need to keep around the environment `s`, but we also can't possibly apply an environment to `e` yet because we don't know what the value for `x` should be.  We're in a bind!

The solution here is to recognize that, while `AST` is a great representation for our input, it is *not* a great representation for the output.  Indeed, it's a bit of a coincidence that input `Int`s and output `Int`s both happen to share the same structure, and for lambdas, perhaps they shouldn't.  So, we can make a new output representation:

```hs
data Val
  = IntV Int
  | LamV (Val -> Val)

type Sub = [(Id, Val)]
```

The key here is that `LamV` is a function, not simply some data.  With this, we can finish our definition of `evalSubsts`:

```hs
evalSubsts :: AST -> Sub -> Val
evalSubsts = cata go where
  go (LetF x e e') s = e' ((x, e s) : s)
  go (VarF x) s = fromJust (lookup x s)
  go (IntF n) _ = IntV n
  go (LamF x e) s = LamV $ \xVal -> e ((x, xVal) : s)
  go (AppF lam e) s =
    let (LamV f) = lam s in f (e s)
  go (PlusF e e') s =
    let (IntV n, IntV m) = (e s, e' s) in
    IntV (n + m)
```